# How to load content before the modal pops up? Angular 2, FullCalendar

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar

I want to display values from the database to the input fields on the modal.

The console sends me an error that it can't see the property of the value I passed in the input field, but after about 3 seconds, It replaces the value with the content in the database sometimes. I just want to correct the inconsistency of showing the data.

Is there a way to load the data way ahead before the modal pops up every time I click an event in fullcalendar?

The modal I am creating is for updating the events.

Thank you!

modal

```
<!-- Edit Event -->
    <ng-template #eventView let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title"> {{view.event_name}} </h4>

        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="namefont">

          <label for="eventTitle">Event Title:</label>
          <input id="eventTitle" class="form-control" type="text" value="{{view.event_name}}"> <br>

          <label for="participants">Participants:</label>
          <input id="participants"class="form-control" type="text" value="{{strParticipants}}" [(ngModel)]="model.participants"> <br>

          <label for="eventStart">Event Start:</label>
          <input id="eventStart" class="form-control" type="date" value=""> <br>

          <label for="eventEnd">Event End:</label>
          <input id="eventEnd" class="form-control" type="date" value=""> <br>

          <label for="startTime">Start Time:</label>
          <input id="startTime" class="form-control"type="time" [(ngModel)]="model.startTime"> <br>

          <label for="endTime">End Time:</label>
          <input id="endTime" class="form-control" type="time" [(ngModel)]="model.endTime"> <br>

          <label for="eventType">Event Type:</label>
          <input id="eventType" class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.eventType"> <br>

          <label for="location">Location:</label>
          <input id="location" class="form-control" type="text" [(ngModel)]="model.location"> <br>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary fa fa-trash" style="float:left;" (click)="deleteEvent()" (click)="c('Close click')"></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="updateEvent()" (click)="c('Close click')">Edit Event</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" (click)="c('Close click')">Close</button>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
```

when clicking the said event(not yet finished)

```
eventClick(model: any) {
this.id = model.event.id;
this.eventService.viewEvent(model.event.id).subscribe(
  viewData => {
    this.view = viewData.data;

    const participants = this.view.participants;
    let parts = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < participants.length; i ++) {
      parts += participants[i].faculty_number + ',' ;
    }
    parts = parts.slice(0, -1);
    console.log(parts);
    this.strParticipants = parts;
  }
);
}

public viewEvent(id): Observable<any> {
const headers = new Headers({
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
});
const url = `${this.baseUrl}api/viewevent/${id}`;
  return this.http.get(url)
  .map((response: Response) => {
      console.log(response.json().data);
      return response.json();
  })
  .catch(err => {
      return Observable.throw(err);
  });
 }
```

Comment: hard to say what is wrong without seeing the relevant code. Sounds like maybe some async execution, e.g. an ajax request is a factor. Possibly you need to delay showing your modal until some other event has occurred (e.g. completion of an ajax request to fetch some data)? I'm just guessing though. No-one can advise you specifically without seeing some code and also the exact error message you receive.

Comment: Hi! I just updated my post! thank you! :D

Comment: It's not clear to my how any of this relates to fullCalendar, except that it's happening on an "eventClick" callback? It's also not clear how your modal is actually shown or populated based on any of that code? All you seem to do is create an array and then stop. Maybe I missed something - I admit I'm not familiar with Angular (I just know fullCalendar) so perhaps that's the key to it?

Comment: may I know how you would incorporate it?

Comment: Incorporate what? I don't understand your question, and you haven't answered any of mine.

Comment: I apologize, the above code populates the modal correctly, however, before it can populate the whole modal, it passes by an error that says that it can't find the current property I have in the value.

In the array, I am iterating over each participant then adding a comma between every one.

how would you incorporate loading everything else before the modal pops up.

thank you! I really appreciate you replying!

Comment: Like I said, I don't understand how you are loading the modal. It's not obvious from your code. Perhaps it's something Angular-specific? Can you explain how the modal is actually populated and shown? What line is throwing the error and what exactly does it say?

Comment: I am getting the info of the clicked event using an api, by passing the id to the api, I use the viewEvent() as shown above. then passing it to the array you see now. the error is "Cannot read property 'event_name'"

Comment: that still doesn't explain how it finds its way into the DOM in a modal, or at what point in the process the modal is being shown. I cannot see any code relating to showing a modal or putting data into the DOM. All I can see is the bit which does the ajax request and populates an array. Then it stops.  Perhaps you can explain - is there some Angular magic I don't understand? I want to help but I've asked you this same thing 3 times now.

Comment: And you forgot to say which line is throwing the error.